# Passing a Function into a Parameter of Another Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a function(average) as a parameter into another function(getAverage).  Then, within the body, I'm trying to call that passed in function(average).  When I call it, it keeps telling me the function is undefined.  Why?

```
var average = function(scores) {
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
while (i < scores.length) {
  total = total + scores[i];
  i++;
}
return total / scores.length;
};

gradebook.getAverage = function(name, average) {
if (name === "Joseph") { average(gradebook.Joseph.testScores); }
};
```

Error: undefined is not a function - referring to average(gradebook....)

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling gradebook.getAverage? You must be passing the wrong parameter to it.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  That was it.  My spec was calling it with just one parameter!

Comment: @xGh0stSn1p3r your advice is wrong. Functions don't need to have names. `===` is actually better than `==`

Comment: Note using `===`is actually a good practice, `==` will match things like `1 == '1'` which is not what you usually want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 gradebook.getAverage = function(name, average) {
   if (name === "Joseph") { average(gradebook.Joseph.testScores); }
 };
```

is declaring a function that will have a parameter called `average`.

You are not using the average function defined in the outer scope but defining a new average parameter for the inner scope that hides the previous declaration.

Just remove the parameter name to use `average` defined in the outer scope:

```
 gradebook.getAverage = function(name) {
   if (name === "Joseph") { average(gradebook.Joseph.testScores); }
 };
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer, but the question doesn't clarify how the function is called in the first place ..

Comment: So make a downvote of the question... not the answer. Is easy to see where the mistake was by looking into the example.

Comment: thanks, yeh.  It's one of those things that became incredibly obvious to me right after I got the first answer on stack overflow, but was driving me crazy trying to figure it out!  I didn't downvote.

Comment: I did not downvote too. Let everyone comment here if they did not downvote. I bet, we gonna find that guilty if we wait enough.